# Wrongly use "git add ." to add hundreds of files from the library "node_modules" directories, how do I undo this before git commit?

Tags: git

I am learning git.

I accidentally used `git add .` and it adds hundreds of files from the "node_modules" directory to my local repository.

Is there anything I can do to undo this before I run the `git commit` command?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the folder:

```
git reset node_modules
```

Then add it to your `.gitignore`

```
echo node_modules/ >> .gitignore
git status
git add .
```

Then it should not add the all content of that folder anymore.

As you can see in [github/gitignore Node.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore#L40-L42), `node_modules/` is usually part of a `.gitignore` file.
Same in [gitignore.io](http://gitignore.io/api/node).

Comment: Thanks, it seems I have missed some very basic tutorials.